# Android In App Billing Access from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, in-app-purchase

I have all the In App Billing code working fine on my MainActivity.
The problem is that I want to access that code from another activity.

The code I'm trying to reach is here on my main Activity:

```
public void buyCode() {
    Log.d(TAG, "2. Button pressed");
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(MainActivity.this, SKU_TEST, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "abc123abc1234");
}
```

I've tried using this code on my OnClickListener on the Other Activity but it's not working, result NullPointerException

```
MainActivity myMainActivity = new MainActivity();
myMainActivity.buyCode();
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of activity by yourself and expect it behaving as a activity created by system. It won't work because system handles all the lifecycle events like create, start, stop, pause etc.

You either need to have a dedicated activity for in-app payments or you need to embed `mHelper` into every activity to execute buying (which is less preferable).

In the first case your main activity must be only responsible for buying operations and handling results. Then you can call it via Intent from any other activity. In the second case you implement same buying logic in multiple activities (which is bad idea) and you don't need to call main activity any longer.

If, in your case, main activity does more, than just handling in-app payments, then you can call it with an additional flag, saying a user want to buy something. You can do it as following.

```
// calling activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("purchase", true);
startActivity(intent);

// MainActivity.java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    boolean executePurchase = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("purchase", false);
    if (executePurchase) {
        // start purchasing logic
        ...
    } else {
        // continue with the standard logic
        ...
    }
}
```

But the `MainActivity` will be started in front of calling activity, and you cannot avoid this with the design you currently have.

Comment: That's great, thanks for your response. I can clearly see that I need to implement "a dedicated activity for in-app payments".
If I move all the in-app billing code into another activity, should I call that activity via intent too (as you've shown here)? Would you mind providing an example, please. Thanks!